# Unroll loop and do independent sum with vectorization

Tags: c, gcc, x86, loop-unrolling, auto-vectorization

For the following loop GCC will only vectorize the loop if I tell it to use associative math e.g. with `-Ofast`.

```
float sumf(float *x)
{
  x = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(x, 64);
  float sum = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<2048; i++) sum += x[i];
  return sum;
}
```

Here is the assembly with `-Ofast -mavx`

```
sumf(float*):
    vxorps  %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
    leaq    8192(%rdi), %rax
.L2:
    vaddps  (%rdi), %ymm0, %ymm0
    addq    $32, %rdi
    cmpq    %rdi, %rax
    jne .L2
    vhaddps %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm0
    vhaddps %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm1
    vperm2f128  $1, %ymm1, %ymm1, %ymm0
    vaddps  %ymm1, %ymm0, %ymm0
    vzeroupper
    ret
```

This clearly shows the loop has been vectorized.

But this loop also has a dependency chain. In order to overcome the latency of the addition I need to unroll and do partial sums at least three times on x86_64 (excluding Skylake which needs to unroll eight times and doing the addition with FMA instructions which need to unroll 10 times on Haswell and Broadwell). As far as I understand I can unroll the loop with `-funroll-loops`.

Here is the assembly with `-Ofast -mavx -funroll-loops`.

```
sumf(float*):
    vxorps  %xmm7, %xmm7, %xmm7
    leaq    8192(%rdi), %rax
.L2:
    vaddps  (%rdi), %ymm7, %ymm0
    addq    $256, %rdi
    vaddps  -224(%rdi), %ymm0, %ymm1
    vaddps  -192(%rdi), %ymm1, %ymm2
    vaddps  -160(%rdi), %ymm2, %ymm3
    vaddps  -128(%rdi), %ymm3, %ymm4
    vaddps  -96(%rdi), %ymm4, %ymm5
    vaddps  -64(%rdi), %ymm5, %ymm6
    vaddps  -32(%rdi), %ymm6, %ymm7
    cmpq    %rdi, %rax
    jne .L2
    vhaddps %ymm7, %ymm7, %ymm8
    vhaddps %ymm8, %ymm8, %ymm9
    vperm2f128  $1, %ymm9, %ymm9, %ymm10
    vaddps  %ymm9, %ymm10, %ymm0
    vzeroupper
    ret
```

GCC does unroll the loop eight times. However, it does not do independent sums. It does eight dependent sums. That's pointless and no better than without unrolling.

**How can I get GCC to unroll the loop and do independent partial sums?**

---

Edit:

Clang unrolls to four independent partial sums even without `-funroll-loops` for SSE but I am not sure its AVX code is as efficient. The compiler should not need `-funroll-loops` with `-Ofast` anyway so it's good to see Clang is doing this right at least for SSE.

Clang 3.5.1 with `-Ofast`.

```
sumf(float*):                              # @sumf(float*)
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    xorps   %xmm1, %xmm1
.LBB0_1:                                # %vector.body
    movups  (%rdi,%rax,4), %xmm2
    movups  16(%rdi,%rax,4), %xmm3
    addps   %xmm0, %xmm2
    addps   %xmm1, %xmm3
    movups  32(%rdi,%rax,4), %xmm0
    movups  48(%rdi,%rax,4), %xmm1
    addps   %xmm2, %xmm0
    addps   %xmm3, %xmm1
    addq    $16, %rax
    cmpq    $2048, %rax             # imm = 0x800
    jne .LBB0_1
    addps   %xmm0, %xmm1
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm2
    movhlps %xmm2, %xmm2            # xmm2 = xmm2[1,1]
    addps   %xmm1, %xmm2
    pshufd  $1, %xmm2, %xmm0        # xmm0 = xmm2[1,0,0,0]
    addps   %xmm2, %xmm0
    retq
```

ICC 13.0.1 with `-O3` unrolls to two independent partial sums.  ICC apparently assumes associative math with only `-O3`.

```
.B1.8: 
    vaddps    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %ymm1, %ymm1                   #5.29
    vaddps    32(%rdi,%rdx,4), %ymm0, %ymm0                 #5.29
    vaddps    64(%rdi,%rdx,4), %ymm1, %ymm1                 #5.29
    vaddps    96(%rdi,%rdx,4), %ymm0, %ymm0                 #5.29
    addq      $32, %rdx                                     #5.3
    cmpq      %rax, %rdx                                    #5.3
    jb        ..B1.8        # Prob 99%                      #5.3
```

Comment: manually add 8 accumulators?

Comment: @user3528438, that defeats the whole purpose of having the compiler do this for me. I would only unroll four times anyway and if I have to do unroll by hand I might as well use intrinsics (which is what I would do in practice anyway). ICC incidentally unrolls to two partial sums. ICC is better.

Comment: I tried with `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum) aligned(x:64)` and `-fopenmp`. That definitely did something more but I can't read enough of assembly to tell whether it fixed your issue. Can you?

Comment: To be fair, I think you're asking too much of the compiler. Give it a few more years maybe?

Comment: @Gilles, I'll look into `omp simd`. I have never used it because I did not see the point of it since the compiler already implements SIMD with the right flags. But apperently it does not do as well as I thought. If `omp simd` does independent partial sums then I would have a reason to use it.

Comment: Cool. Please let me know if it works as I'm really curious about that, and unfortunately, I'm not a great assembly reader.

Comment: @Gilles, speaking of which I have always wanted something like '#pragma unroll 4'. It's annoying to unroll by hand everytime. That's one reason assembly is awesome. I did that with NASM [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899395/obtaining-peak-bandwidth-on-haswell-in-the-l1-cache-only-getting-62) using a macro `%rep    unroll`

Comment: @I tried `omp simd` but it made no difference. However, I did notice that I did not have to use `-Ofast`.  As far as I can tell `omp simd` with `-O2` is the same as just using `-Ofast`.

Comment: @Mysticial, or I could just use Clang. I updated my answer with the assembly from Clang and it does the right thing at least for SSE.

Comment: Those unaligned loads in the clang version tho.

Comment: @EOF Unaligned load/stores have no penalty for aligned addresses since Nehalem.

Comment: @EOF, unaligned loads are not really a problem since Nehalem. But anyway I am not very familiar with Clang. Maybe there is a way to tell it to assume the array is aligned. I'm intrigued with Clang now but unfortunately even though it has OpenMP support now [it does not compete with GCC](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=llvm_clang_openmp&num=2). I can fix the unrolling myself in GCC but I can't easily replace OpenMP.

Comment: @Mysticial But the unaligned load *does* preclude just using a memory operand (though it seems `-march=core-avx2` allows unaligned memory operands to `vaddps`).

Comment: @EOF: AVX memory operands don't fault on unaligned.  Only `vmovdqa` (and other explicitly-aligned load/store AVX insns) fault on unaligned addresses.

Comment: @Zboson: Skylake has 4-cycle latency `vaddps`, with a throughput of 2 per cycle.  (It drops the 3c FP add unit, and uses the 4-cycle latency FMA units for adds as well as multiplies.)  You need 8 vector accumulators to saturate Skylake's FP throughput for add, mul, or fma.  I completely agree that it would be really nice if compiler unrolling was smarter about using more accumulators.  [clang 3.7 on godbolt](https://goo.gl/YGgN8x) uses 4, but pointlessly unrolls more than that.  (uop caches are small, so unroll only as much as needed.  gcc only unrolls by default with `-fprofile-use`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks for the info on Skylake. I was not aware of that. Where do you get your Skylake info? I could also have used fma (`a+b=a*1.0+b`) with Haswell and Broadwell. Then I would need to unroll 10 times but it would double my throughput. I'll fix my question shortly.

Comment: @PeterCordes, your code at godbolt is really intersting. Clang does better than the other compilers. But I don't think Clang supports `omp simd`. That's from OpenMP 4.0 and Clang does not support that yet as far as I know. It should warn you about that with `-Wall` but it does not for me but if I use `omp asdf` it gives not warning either. In any case the binaries are identical with and without it.

Comment: @PeterCordes, incidentally, are you interested in Skylake? I was hugely disappointed in Intel dropping AVX512. My real time ray tracer I wrote in OpenCL for my GTX580 which is six years old still beats every Intel processor I have used by a good margin and this was before I knew much about optimization. Intel only cares about IoT and low power now for the consumer market. They only want to sell scooters now...

Comment: @Zboson: I saw the news months before launch that AVX512 wasn't going to be in the desktop models.  I was disappointed that not all Skylake Xeons will have AVX512, though.  Only Skylake-EP cores will, not Xeons based on the quad-core desktop silicon.  What I'm disappointed about recently is that they're not making any socketed desktop Skylake chips with eDRAM.  So Broadwell-C beats Skylake on some benchmarks, like rar and 7z compression.  For some parallelizable workloads, sure GPGPU is the way to go.  I'm not that surprised that a GTX580 is still competitive.

Comment: @Zboson: Skylake insn lat/tput from an AIDA64 run someone linked on realworldtech.  I put links into this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/c-loop-optimization-help-for-final-assignment/32001196#32001196 and this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002277/why-does-gcc-or-clang-not-optimise-reciprocal-to-1-instruction-when-using-fast-m/32002316#comment51941322_32002316

Comment: @PeterCordes, I was not aware AVX512 was only for Skeylake-EP. That explains why the mobile skylake xeon processors don't have AVX512.

Comment: @PeterCordes, you mentioned GCC unrolling only with `-fprofile-use`. I have never used this. Do you have experience with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881292/gcc-profile-guided-optimization-pgo

Comment: @Zboson: not a lot, but it's generally recommended if you can run the binary made with `-fprofile-generate` in a way that exercises all the code paths that should be fast.  (i.e. make sure any loops that should be unrolled actually get run with the profile-generation test data set.)  x264's Makefile has a profile-generate option that encodes a sample video (which you have to provide) with a few different encoder settings, then builds with `-fprofile-use`.  I assume the design goal is to only unroll hot loops, and leave cold loops more compact.  And only inline where useful, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some use of gcc intrinsics and `__builtin_` produce this:

```
typedef float v8sf __attribute__((vector_size(32)));
typedef uint32_t v8u32 __attribute__((vector_size(32)));

static v8sf sumfvhelper1(v8sf arr[4])
{
  v8sf retval = {0};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    retval += arr[i];
  return retval;
}

static float sumfvhelper2(v8sf x)
{
  v8sf t = __builtin_shuffle(x, (v8u32){4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3});
  x += t;
  t = __builtin_shuffle(x, (v8u32){2,3,0,1,6,7,4,5});
  x += t;
  t = __builtin_shuffle(x, (v8u32){1,0,3,2,5,4,7,6});
  x += t;
  return x[0];
}

float sumfv(float *x)
{
  //x = __builtin_assume_aligned(x, 64);
  v8sf *vx = (v8sf*)x;
  v8sf sumvv[4] = {{0}};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 2048/8; i+=4)
    {
      sumvv[0] += vx[i+0];
      sumvv[1] += vx[i+1];
      sumvv[2] += vx[i+2];
      sumvv[3] += vx[i+3];
    }
  v8sf sumv = sumfvhelper1(sumvv);
  return sumfvhelper2(sumv);
}
```

Which gcc 4.8.4 `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu11 -march=native -O3 -fno-signed-zeros -fno-trapping-math -freciprocal-math -ffinite-math-only -fassociative-math -S` turns into:

```
sumfv:
    vxorps  %xmm2, %xmm2, %xmm2
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    vmovaps %ymm2, %ymm3
    vmovaps %ymm2, %ymm0
    vmovaps %ymm2, %ymm1
.L7:
    addq    $4, %rax
    vaddps  (%rdi), %ymm1, %ymm1
    subq    $-128, %rdi
    vaddps  -96(%rdi), %ymm0, %ymm0
    vaddps  -64(%rdi), %ymm3, %ymm3
    vaddps  -32(%rdi), %ymm2, %ymm2
    cmpq    $256, %rax
    jne .L7
    vaddps  %ymm2, %ymm3, %ymm2
    vaddps  %ymm0, %ymm1, %ymm0
    vaddps  %ymm0, %ymm2, %ymm0
    vperm2f128  $1, %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm1
    vaddps  %ymm0, %ymm1, %ymm0
    vpermilps   $78, %ymm0, %ymm1
    vaddps  %ymm0, %ymm1, %ymm0
    vpermilps   $177, %ymm0, %ymm1
    vaddps  %ymm0, %ymm1, %ymm0
    vzeroupper
    ret
```

The second helper function isn't strictly necessary, but summing over the elements of a vector tends to produce terrible code in gcc. If you're willing to do platform-dependent intrinsics, you can probably replace most of it with `__builtin_ia32_hadps256()`.