# Replace STL allocator with custom allocator

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, allocation

I followed this link:
[Replace default STL allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247552/replace-default-stl-allocator)

to replace the standard allocator with my own custom allocator.
But I am getting this error:

> /grid/common/pkgsData/gcc-v4.8.3/Linux/RHEL5.0-2010-x86_64/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/allocator.h:92:45: error: expected template-name before '<' token
>
> ```
> class allocator: public __allocator_base<_Tp>
>                                          ^
> ```

Somehow allocator.h file is not able to find out my custom allocator class.
I used GCC:4.8.3
I added `bits/` folder inside my source include folder, and created c++allocator.h. Inside this file defined marco similar to GCC provided c++allocator.h (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00780_source.html).

```
#define __glibcxx_base_allocator my_allocator
```

my_allocator is my custom allocator.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: added some for details

Comment: Overloading the `new` operator would be way easier and standard compliant (without resorting to any trick), so if you aren't interested in replacing the allocator *just for STL containers* it's probably an easier route.

Comment: my source code contains more than 300 files and each file is using tons of vector, string. I am considering overloading new/delete as my last option. @MatteoItalia

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm talking about overloading the *global* `new` operator, which would catch all of them without touching any line of the existing files. BTW, if you explain why you want to do this we could better help you.

Comment: I am using memory pool for my custom allocator. This memory pool has some variance depending on the size of memory. Also, my application is multi-threaded (~400 threads) and application needs to be run more months without any reboot. I want to avoid memory fragmentation problem.